# SQL to DetachedCriteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Здравствуйте возникла проблема с hibernate.

Есть запрос бд:

```
SELECT * FROM engine WHERE type = 'java' AND id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM engine GROUP BY keyword);
```

Нужно переделать под `DetachedCriteria`.

Вот до чего доошёл сам:

```
DetachedCriteria subCriteria = getDetachedCriteriaDistinctRootEntity();

ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.max("id"));
projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("keyword"));

subCriteria.setProjection(projectionList);

criteria.add(Subqueries.in("id", subCriteria));
```

Проблема в том, что подзапрос возвращает поле `id` и `keyword`, а чистый sql только id и соответственно возникает ошибка. как сделать такое же поведение в Hibernate 3.6.